# Jquery Selectors to Get Background Color

Tags: jquery

I currently have  several divisions with an svg in each. I want to get the next div's (targeted by class) background color through jquery and apply it as css fill for the previous parents svg. I tried to use nextAll and prevAll and but it doesnt work.

[view sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZEP2.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please paste some code :) html and jquery you used preferably.

Comment: [Heres What I got So far](https://jsfiddle.net/ondesignsme/f2gdnozq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.awesome').each(function(){
var theColor = $(this).css( "background-color" );

$(this).prev().find('svg').css( "fill", theColor);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="awesome" style="background-color:white;">
<svg id="curveUpColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
<div class="awesome" style="background-color:blue;">
<svg id="curveUpColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
<div class="awesome" style="background-color:black;">
<svg id="curveUpColorr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
<div class="awesome" style="background-color:red;">
<svg id="curveUpColorrrr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The nextAll() method returns all next sibling elements of the selected element.

Sibling elements are elements that share the same parent.

i think that your div is not same parent 
try this:

$(".target_class").parent().parent().find("div")

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //this will get first child of division with awesome classname
  var theColor = $("div.awesome:first").css("background-color");

  //this will get all the svg(s) except first 
  $("div.awesome").find("svg:not(:first)").css("background-color", theColor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="awesome" style="background-color:white;">
  <svg id="curveUpColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>

<div class="awesome" style="background-color:blue;">
  <svg id="curveUpColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>

<div class="awesome" style="background-color:black;">
  <svg id="curveUpColorr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>

<div class="awesome" style="background-color:red;">
  <svg id="curveUpColorrrr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
```